# "Program received signal "SIGABRT" when building a calculator

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

(I'm beginner.)
I'm practicing Navigation Controller. I try to implement a simple calculator.

I ran the code in simulator. After I pressed any button which was linked to "addFunction", "substractFunction", "multiplyFunction" or "divideFunction", It crashed.

The debugger marked the following code in main.m

```
int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil);
```

and said "Thread 1: Program received signal: "SIGABRT"."

Does anyone know how to cope with this situation? Thanks.

Here's the code:

ChangeAppView.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@class ChangeViewController;
@interface ChangeAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate>
{
    UIWindow *window;
    UINavigationController *navigationController;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UINavigationController *navigationController;
@end
```

ChangeAppDelegate.m:

```
#import "ChangeAppDelegate.h"
#import "ChangeViewController.h"

@implementation ChangeAppDelegate
@synthesize window;
@synthesize navigationController;
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] init]; 
    self.window.rootViewController = navigationController; 
    ChangeViewController *changeViewController = [[ChangeViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ChangeViewController" bundle:nil]; 
    [navigationController pushViewController:changeViewController animated:YES];
    [changeViewController release];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible]; 
    return YES;
}
```

…

```
- (void)dealloc
{
    [navigationController release];
    [window release];
    [super dealloc];
}
@end
```

CalculatorViewController.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface CalculatorViewController : UIViewController 
{
    IBOutlet UITextField *numberField1;
    IBOutlet UITextField *numberField2;
    IBOutlet UILabel *resultLabel;
}
@property (nonatomic , retain) IBOutlet UITextField *numberField1;
@property (nonatomic , retain) IBOutlet UITextField *numberField2;
@property (nonatomic , retain) IBOutlet UILabel *resultLabel;
-(IBAction)addFunction:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)substractFunction:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)multiplyFunction:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)divideFunction:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)clear:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)backgroundTap:(id)sender;
@end
```

CalculatorViewController.m:

```
#import "CalculatorViewController.h"
@implementation CalculatorViewController
@synthesize numberField1;
@synthesize numberField2;
@synthesize resultLabel;
-(IBAction)addFunction:(id)sender
{
    float a = ([numberField1.text floatValue]);
    float b = ([numberField2.text floatValue]);    
    resultLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%2.f" , a+b];
}

-(IBAction)substractFunction:(id)sender
{
    float a = ([numberField1.text floatValue]);
    float b = ([numberField2.text floatValue]);
    NSString *result = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%2.f" , a-b];
    resultLabel.text = result;
    [result release];
}

-(IBAction)multiplyFunction:(id)sender
{
    float a = ([numberField1.text floatValue]);
    float b = ([numberField2.text floatValue]);
    resultLabel.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%2.f" , a*b];
}

-(IBAction)divideFunction:(id)sender
{
    float a = ([numberField1.text floatValue]);
    float b = ([numberField2.text floatValue]);
    resultLabel.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%2.3f" , a/b];
}

-(IBAction)clear:(id)sender
{
    numberField1.text = @"";
    numberField2.text = @"";
    resultLabel.text = @"";
}

-(IBAction)backgroundTap:(id)sender
{
    [numberField1 resignFirstResponder];
    [numberField2 resignFirstResponder];
}

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [numberField1 release];
    [numberField2 release];
    [resultLabel release];
    [super dealloc];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];  
    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    self.title = @"Calculator";
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}
@end
```

Comment: Have you set Outlet for all buttons? Check it in Interface Builder.

Comment: Set break point to one of the IBAction method and let me know the exact line.

Comment: 2011-08-20 19:57:48.426 Change[28442:207] -[UIView addTarget:action:forControlEvents:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4e27870
2011-08-20 19:57:48.430 Change[28442:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIView addTarget:action:forControlEvents:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4e27870'

Comment: In IB, is it showing any warning?

Comment: I didn't see any warning in Interface Builder.

Answer (score 1):

From the exception above, it seems that your IBActions are not properly connected.
As dasdom mentioned, delete all your buttons, create new buttons and then add IBAction methods accordingly.

Also one more thing i recognized in your code, in the multiply and divide methods there is a memory leak.You have written

```
resultLabel.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%2.f" , a*b];
```

it should be

```
resultLabel.text = [[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%2.f" , a*b]autorelease];
```

or

```
resultLabel.text = [NSString StringWithFormat:@"%2.f" , a*b];
```

and do a similar change in divide method also.

**To what did you link your backgroundtap method?**

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you buttons aren't buttons. They seem to be view. Delete the buttons from you nib and put new buttons there and link them you our IBActions.

Comment: If they are in fact buttons, change their class in IB through the third inspector (Command-Option-3)

Comment: I've check the Identity Inspector. Each of the button belongs to the "UIButton" Class.

Comment: How did you set the connection. Control click on the button an then drag a line into the .h file?

Comment: Click on the button. Ctrl-click on "Touch up inside" and drag a line onto File's Owner and choose the method.